# Substract values depending on multiple key columns on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to make a substraction of all values in a column C, for each row where A & B are the same.

I have:

```
 A          B          C
Car        Wheel      4
Car        Wheel      2
Plane      Motor      -10
Plane      Motor      -5
Plane      Wheel      12
```

And I need:

```
 A          B          C
Car        Wheel    4-2 = 2
Plane      Motor   -10-(-5) = -5
Plane      Wheel      12
```

I actually had something similar with the df.groupby(['A','B']).sum(), the problem is that I didn't found an equivalent for substraction... pd.sub seems to be used for inter-dataframes operations and not only on one column.

Comment: what happens when there are three items? or is it always either one or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate `sum`, only multiple duplicated values by `-1`, so output is aggregate subtraction:

```
print (df.assign(C = np.where(df.duplicated(['A','B']), -1, 1) * df.C))
       A      B   C
0    Car  Wheel   4
1    Car  Wheel  -2
2  Plane  Motor -10
3  Plane  Motor   5
4  Plane  Wheel  12

df1 = (df.assign(C = np.where(df.duplicated(['A','B']), -1, 1) * df.C)
         .groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False)['C'].sum())
print (df1)
       A      B   C
0    Car  Wheel   2
1  Plane  Motor  -5
2  Plane  Wheel  12
```

Comment: Great Idea, multiplying with -1 and adding them. Awesome!!.